# Add integer value to function method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function I call with `nameOfFunction();` the output of the function is an integer eg. `10`.

I also have `var number = 5;`.

I cannot change the function `nameOfFunction();` or substitute it with another variable.

Is there a way to add `number` to `nameOfFunction();` so the output of `nameOfFunction();` will equal 15?

Like this:

`nameOfFunction() + number = nameOfFunction();`

output would be

`10 + 5 = 15`

Edit with more info: NameOfFunction(); is the total cost of all items in the cart of my ecommerce site. It is the output of all the functions required to calculate the number of items and their amounts.

The number variable is the delivery charge that changes depending on the amount in the cart. The total is rendered using `NameOfFunction();` and the value posted to a form.

I need to manipulate the output of `NameOfFunction();` with altering the functions that define it. Adding `number` must occur after.

I cant show the code as it is obtuse and out of context would not make sense.

Comment: is it a normal defined function? that is in the regular window scope? If so you can use something like `var org= nameOfFunction;
nameOfFunction = function(){return org() + 5;}`

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking or what the **real** limitations are. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)), and be crystal-clear about **why** you (think you) *"cannot change the function nameOfFunction(); or substitute it with another variable."*

Comment: @Me.Name that seems like what I need. When I call `nameOf Function` the output will be 15 right?

Comment: If you cannot show the original code, at least post a relevantly simple version of it, so when someone provides an answer, you can implement the changes yourself.

Comment: @pathurs this is what I need `nameOfFunction() + number = nameOfFunction();`

Comment: As pathurs said: *"If you cannot show the original code, at least post a relevantly simple version of it"* E.g., as I said above, an [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: @JPB: Just repeating in a comment what you've said in the question doesn't do anything to help us help you. Actually answering the questions above, and providing the requested MCVE, would help us help you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I replied to both @Me.Name and @Kannan. I'm sorry I cannot be more clear with a code example but I thought what I provided showed the intent. Just not sure how to acheive. `nameOfFunction` and `number ` are already defined, just need to add them togther and call the new total with `nameOfFunction`.

Comment: @JPB: There **is** no code example in the question. It's not hard to be more clear than nothing at all...

Comment: You got it though. This was the code example `nameOfFunction() + number = nameOfFunction();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot change the function nameOfFunction(); or substitute it with another variable.

From your subsequent comments, my guess (and the guess of a now-edited and -deleted answer — apologies to [Ele](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1715121/ele), you got it right) is that you *can*, you just don't *realize* you can. In a normal scenario, this will do it (not the same as that deleted answer, stuck to ES3-level features):

```
var oldFunction = nameOfFunction;
nameOfFunction = function() {
    return oldFunction.apply(this, arguments) + 5;
};
```

The identifier (technically, *binding*) of the function is writable by default, so the above remembers the old function, then replaces the value of its binding with a new function that calls the original and adds 5 to the result. The code uses [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FFunctions_and_function_scope%2Farguments) to ensure that both `this` and all arguments passed to the function are passed on by the wrapper.

Now, all calls to `nameOfFunction` will see the old function's return value with 5 added to it.

Live Example:

```js
// The original function
function nameOfFunction(n) {
  return n * 15 + 7;
}

// Us hijacking it:
var oldFunction = nameOfFunction;
nameOfFunction = function() {
    return oldFunction.apply(this, arguments) + 5;
};

// All calls to it will now see the new return value:
console.log(nameOfFunction(2)); // 42
```

Comment: Yes that's what I need thanks for your patience and explanation.

Comment: @JPB: I reverted the edit, as it made it stop working. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry about that. This was my intent: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QQpJrZ?editors=1111

Comment: @JPB: I saw the code. I asked what you're trying to achieve. In particular, replacing the body of `nameOfFunction` with just `10;` means the function doesn't return anything (and the `10;` is a pointless statement).

Comment: 10 is just a placeholder for the actual output of the function call which is a number. The pen works as intended thanks to you. I think my terminology might be off.

Comment: @JPB: But again, calling `function nameOfFunction() { 10; }` will not return anything. You need `return 10;`, not just `10;`.

Comment: Check the pen again.

Comment: Cool. .........

Answer (score 0):

Store in a temporary variable whatever your nameOfFunction returns and add whatever value you want to add to that.

```
let nameOfFunction = function() {
    return 10;
}
let temp= nameOfFunction();
let ans = temp+5;
console.log(nameOfFunction()+5);
```

Comment: The problem is that the new output must be called with `nameOfFunction();`

Comment: Check the edited version is that fine?

Comment: Would this work (output of nameOfFunction is 10)
`var number = 5; let temp= nameOfFunction();
let ans = temp+number;
console.log(15);`